# Data frame output not matching expected output

Tags: r

I have a function which takes a data frame and gives basic summary statistics.  My problem is, the function output is not matching the expected output.

```
# create my data frame
x = c(55.3846, 54.5385, 54.1538, 54.8205, 54.7692, 54.7179)
y = c(47.1795, 47.0256, 47.4872, 47.4103, 47.3333, 47.8718)
df = data.frame(x,y)

# create function to create summary statistics
xy_stats <- function(data) {
x_mean <- mean(data$x)
y_mean <- mean(data$y)
x_sd <- sd(data$x)
y_sd <- sd(data$y)
corr <- cor(data$x,data$y, method = "pearson")
xydata <- data.frame(x_mean, y_mean, x_sd, y_sd, corr)
return(xydata)
}

# test function on data frame
df_results <- xy_stats(df)
```

This produces the output:

```
> xy_stats(df)
    x_mean   y_mean      x_sd      y_sd       corr
1 54.73075 47.38462 0.4017586 0.2905615 -0.2230826
```

Then I create the expected output:

```
# create test data (expected output)
test_data <- c(
            "x_mean" = 54.26,
            "y_mean" = 47.83,
            "x_sd" = 0.46,
            "y_sd" = 0.29,
            "corr" = -0.265
         )
```

Which looks like:

```
> test_data
x_mean y_mean   x_sd   y_sd   corr 
54.260 47.830  0.460  0.290 -0.265
```

I then compare the function output and the expected output:

```
library(testthat)
expect_equal(df_results,test_data,tolerance=1)
```

The output is as follows:

```
Error: `df_results` not equal to `test_data`.
Modes: list, numeric
Attributes: < names for target but not for current >
Attributes: < Length mismatch: comparison on first 0 components >
```

I cannot adjust the expected (test_data) results, but I can adjust the function to create an output that matches the expected results.  I can see that the class of the test_data is numeric and the class of the df results is data.frame, but I don't know how to get the results produced by the function to be numeric.  I have tried replacing the following in the code but it does not work:

```
# Replace:
xydata <- data.frame(x_mean, y_mean, x_sd, y_sd, corr)
# with:
xydata <- data.frame(as.numeric(x_mean, y_mean, x_sd, y_sd, corr))
```

Comment: How do you get `test_data`?

Comment: I have written above what test_data is (third coding box down)

Comment: well... I mean, how do you calculate those statistics? manually?

Comment: Yes, in reality it's a bit more complicated but I have simplified it to this.  It is a group of numbers of set value.

Comment: From you code in `xy_stats`, I didn't see anything wrong for the statistics in terms of calculation methods

Comment: It's not the calculation that is the problem, it is that the data object type doesn't match the expected data object type - basically I need the expect_equal function (from the testthat) package to work without error messages.

Comment: now you can try my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below to unlist `df_results` to array

```
expect_equal(unlist(df_results),test_data,tolerance=1)
```

which gives no error messages

Comment: I need to adjust the output of the function rather than the test_data or the expect_equal function

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `test_data` is a named vector, whereas the output of `xy_stats` is a data frame.

Why not just make the output of `xy_stats` a named vector instead:

```
xy_stats <- function(data) 
{
  c("x_mean" = mean(data$x), 
    "y_mean" = mean(data$y), 
    "x_sd"   = sd(data$x), 
    "y_sd"   = sd(data$y), 
    "corr"   = cor(data$x, data$y, method = "pearson"))
}
```

Now when you do

```
df_results <- xy_stats(df)

test_data <- c(
            "x_mean" = 54.26,
            "y_mean" = 47.83,
            "x_sd" = 0.46,
            "y_sd" = 0.29,
            "corr" = -0.265
         )

expect_equal(df_results, test_data, tolerance = 1)
```

It passes without error

Comment: I can't adjust the format of test_data in reality.  I know this would be the optimal solution but in reality I can't do this.  I have to adjust the output of the function.

Comment: @icedcoffee then do it the other way round - see my updated answer